# Excel worksheets error: One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, telerik

I am trying to get the Excel sheet cell values to be used as inputs in a test script.

I have been following the http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-pass-excel-worksheet-name-path-as-string

```
        string myPath = @"C:\Users\Monica\Desktop\ExcelTest.xlsx";
        Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(myPath);

        //select the correct worksheet

        Excel.Worksheet demoWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelApp.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
```

I am trying to select the worksheet "Sheet1" from Workbook "ExcelTest.xlsx" and getting the following error

> "One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found".

Comment: Monica, thank you for asking this question with all the right search terms. I'd been working on this for a couple of hours, looking at syntax, etc, before I thought to just search on the trying-to-be-helpful error message.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try removing the "Microsoft.CSharp" reference then add it back your project.

Comment: Or, just add it in for the first time. Bahh! (to MS and VS). Thank you (to Patrick)

Comment: in My case it was removed. then i just added It. thank you!!